# How to get Istanbul working with Sails.js 0.10.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sails.js, istanbul

I am trying to get the Istanbul code coverage tool working with a Sails.js 0.10.x app.

I saw http://blog.sergiocruz.me/unit-test-sailsjs-with-mocha-and-instanbul-for-code-coverage/ but this uses 0.9.x, and following the same steps with 0.10.x doesn't work because of changes to the Grunt setup.

I tried to adapt it as follows:

- `tasks/config/istanbulCoverage.js`:

  ```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('mocha_istanbul', {
      coverage: {
        src: 'test',
        options: {
          coverageFolder: 'coverage',
          mask: '**/*.spec.js',
          root: 'api/'
        }
      }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-istanbul');
  };
  ```
- `tasks/register/coverage.js`:

  ```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('coverage', [
      'mocha_istanbul:coverage'
    ]);
  };
  ```

But this results in only the `/coverage` directory being created but no files being created within it.

There are no error messages, all tests pass and everything seems fine except that no coverage report is created.

Anyone know what's wrong? I am on Windows if that matters, but will try a *nix VM later.

Comment: Looks like a problem with sails.lower() in 0.10.x. It removes all listeners including apparently Istanbul's! https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1883#issuecomment-46927318

Comment: Did you ever get this working @blah238?

Comment: @JasonKulatunga Yes, it's fixed in Sails' master branch, but there is not an npm release with it yet. See the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Sails to v0.10.4. My configuration is similar to you except I use `grunt.registerTask('test',...)`. Then run `grunt test`. It works well including the coverage report. Take a try on it.